# How to "Set previous context mark"?

Tags: vimscript, cursor-movement, mark

From the vim manual:

```
m'  or  m`      Set the previous context mark.  This can be jumped to
            with the "''" or "``" command (does not move the
            cursor, this is not a motion command).
```

I could not understand what this does or what its used for, tried to "set" previous mark to another mark using that, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'` and `` ` `` are synonymous.
It correspond to position before the last move (with the exception of the very small moves. e.g. one character, one line)

The `m'` (and its sister: `` m` ``):

- Set the last position mark explicitly
- Add an entry at the top of jump list
- Move the jump list cursor to the to of the it

I believe this command is used by plugin developers when they create moves.

It let them:

- Mark the original position before the jump
- Maintain the jump list

This to make the jump commands works like expected:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>
- `''`
- `` `' ``

Comment: Thanks! This can be verified by visiting the jump list (:jumps). j or k are not jumps while the mentioned m`, or m' somewhere would create a jump record.